# How to refresh data in a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, promise

In the following code, what I want to achieve is to make the `return $http.get(newurl_3);` call every 10 second and refresh the data in the last response. I tried setInterval in different places but could not make it work.

it is actually a chains of promises in 5 steps and in total are more than 100+ line of code. not sure if putting the whole thing in a setInterval is a good practice.

```
$http.get(url).then(function(data) {
    // playing with data and returning a new promise
    return $http.get(newurl_1); 
}).then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_2); 
}).then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_3); 
}).then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_4); // this call only needs to be refreshed. 
}).then(function (data) {
    // creating data array for UI. 
    // needs to be refreshed every 10 second to fetch updated data. 
    $scope.UI_presentation_Array = data... 
})
```

Comment: call the whole chain `$http.get(url).then(function(data) { ...` etc every 10 seconds - because the `data` in `.then(function (data) {` can't magically change

Comment: @JaromandaX this is 5 chain in total 150 lines of code. :|

Comment: put it in a function, call the function in setInterval

Comment: @JaromandaX only the last 2 chain should refresh. other than that app gets very slow and code gets ugly.

Comment: You've shown a single chain. So talk of 2 or 5 chains makes little sense

Comment: @JaromandaX I added more info.

Comment: It's still a single chain. Now with more "links"

Comment: @DragonKnight, do you really mean "5 chains of promises"? The code exhibits **one** chain comprising five "steps" - an initial promise with four chained .thens . Maybe you would like to reconsider your wording.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thats true. Ill edit it now.

Comment: @DragonKnight Then put only the last two `then` calls in the interval. Store the promise that the method will be called on in a variable.

Comment: @Bergi can you write how? what I wrote through an error.

Comment: @DragonKnight What *did* you write? Please post your attempt.

Comment: @Bergi simply wrapped the code in the 4th block and last block separately in a function and called it in a setInterval in the same block.

Comment: @DragonKnight That won't work of course, because the two blocks don't know they depend on each other that way. Don't put them separately in intervals, but after the third step trigger the interval that repeatedly does the rest of the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider that your promise chain can be written, as follows:

```
var promise = $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
    // playing with data and returning a new promise
    return $http.get(newurl_1); 
}).then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_2); 
});

promise.then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_3); // this call only needs to be refreshed. 
}).then(function (data) {
    // creating data array for UI. 
    // needs to be refreshed every 10 second to fetch updated data. 
    $scope.UI_presentation_Array = data... 
});
```

Note that the break, comes immediately before the step at which refresh needs to occur. So now, `promise` is the static part of the process and `promise.then()...` is the part you want to repeat.

Now wrap the repeated part in `function refresh() {...}` and call `refresh` from your `setInterval`, giving, in full :

```
var promise = $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
    // playing with data and returning a new promise
    return $http.get(newurl_1); 
}).then(function (data) {
    return $http.get(newurl_2); 
});

function refresh() {
    return promise.then(function (data) {
        return $http.get(newurl_3); // this call only needs to be refreshed. 
    }).then(function (data) {
        // creating data array for UI. 
        // needs to be refreshed every 10 second to fetch updated data. 
        $scope.UI_presentation_Array = data... 
    });
}

var intervalRef = setInterval(refresh, 10000);
```

That will probably suffice due to the fairly long interval of 10s. Unless the gets are very laggy, you won't suffer "overlap" - ie where a get cycle starts before the preceding one has completed.

For full safety though, you should consider calling `refresh()` not from a `setInterval` but on completion of previous cycle plus a delay.

Comment: thanks, breaking it seems a better idea than wrapping the whole thing. I think assigning that part to a variable and cleanly refresh a function that only returns a promise would be an addition. btw I am not sure yet how to deal with speed yet.

Comment: I found that only last two blocks are refreshed not the whole chain. dont know why yet but interesting.

Comment: @DragonKnight, that comment is slightly worrying. I thought that refreshing only the last two blocks was the objective of the exercise, and the whole answer was written on that basis.

Comment: Thats correct answer. only refreshes last two blocks. It actually solved my other problem too which I wanted to use the response of first block more times without executing it again. thumbs up.

Comment: Hey, I'm mightily relieved. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole chain is required to load the data then you probably don't have a choice and have to call it the same way each time

```
function load() {    
    $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
        // playing with data and returning a promise
        return $http.get(newurl); 
    }).then(function (data) {
        // creating data array for UI. 
        // needs to be refreshed every 10 second to fetch updated data. 
        $scope.UI_presentation_Array = data... 
    })
}
setInterval( load, 10000);
```

Comment: only the last 2 requests needs to reload. that gets really ugly and slow if I do that.

Comment: I am not sure I follow then.  You are calling `url` in $http.get(url)` and in subsequent `.then` you are making another `promise` call which returns you  what you need.  Do the other promises (in the chain you mention) play a role in getting `$scope.UI_presentation_Array`?

Comment: yes its a long chain of elastic search requests to achieve the last request. the data for the last table only refreshes. the previous ones are static.

Comment: Then I can't see any other way than to include all of them inside the function.